# Hashicorp Vault behind nginx reverse proxy

Tags: authorization, nginx-reverse-proxy, hashicorp-vault, cidr

I am trying to use vault behind nginx proxy, using App role auth method within vault. I need to apply `secret_id_bound_cidrs` as one of the restrictions for the role so only specific hosts can login and access Vault APIs. I have tried everything, and the closest I got was to use proxy protocol  options in vault. However, when I send a request to vault from a host, the `remote_add` in vault is set to the server hosting vault and not the actual client IP, so the validation fails.
My `nginx.conf` is as follows :

```
location /vault/
{         
proxy_set_header X-Real-Ip $remote_addr;         
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for; 
proxy_set_header Host $host;         
proxy_set_header REMOTE_ADDR $remote_addr;        
proxy_pass    http://vault:8200/;             
}
```

My vault config is as follows:
Please note, I am using consul and vault as docker services which allows me to refer to consul as just the name of the service here. Hence `consul:8500`

```
{
  "backend": {
    "consul": {
      "address": "consul:8500",
      "path": "vault/"
    }
  },
  "listener": {
    "tcp":{
      "address": "0.0.0.0:8200",
      "tls_disable": 1
    }
  },
  "proxy_protocol_behavior":"use_always",
  "ui": true
}
```

My role is configured as follows where x.x.x.x is the IP I need to allow access to:

```
bind_secret_id             false
local_secret_ids           false
policies                   [test-policy]
secret_id_bound_cidrs      [ x.x.x.x/32]
secret_id_num_uses         0
secret_id_ttl              0s
token_bound_cidrs          []
token_explicit_max_ttl     0s
token_max_ttl              30m
token_no_default_policy    false
token_num_uses             0
token_period               0s
token_policies             [test-policy]
token_ttl                  20m
token_type                 default
```

Can someone please help with any pointers on what I am missing here?

Answer (score 0):

The `proxy_protocol_behaviour` field belongs in the `listener/tcp` block, but you have it out on its own.

Aside from that, I'm not 100% certain that NGINX will use the right PROXY protocol with the way you have set it up - see these sites for more comments:

- https://github.com/hashicorp/vault/issues/3196
- https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/load-balancer/using-proxy-protocol/#proxy_protocol